# Kivy camera get image

Tags: camera, kivy

I am trying to use kivy to capture an image of a QR.
Using

```
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
self.cameraObject = Camera(play=True,resolution=(640,480),index=0)
```

I successfully captured an image which I can save to a file

```
self.cameraObject.export_to_png('./selfie.png')
```

I wish to get the picture into a variable then used to check for QR codes. I could read the image in from the file I just saved but the image is already stored in the camera object. I am unable to find a Camera method that returns the image.
What I would like to do is something like;

```
frame=self.cameraObject.get_image()
```

Sadly this doesn't seem to exist and I cannot see a likely command in the Camera methods list. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a reference to the `Texture` of the `Camera` `Image` using:

```
texture = self.cameraObject.texture
```

Note that `texture` will change with each frame the `Camera` captures.

You can get the array of pixels from the `Texture`:

```
pixels = texture.pixels
```

Comment: The problem then is to convert the pixels to a numpy array image. I tried pil_image = Image.frombytes(mode='RGBA', size=size,data=frame) I'm playing in the dark here.

Answer (score 2):

Okay that worked....so

```
import numpy
from PIL import Image

texture = self.cameraObject.texture
size=texture.size
pixels = texture.pixels
pil_image=Image.frombytes(mode='RGBA', size=size,data=pixels)
numpypicture=numpy.array(pil_image)
```

Thank you Mr Anderson

Comment: It only captures the 1st frame of the Camera() object. Any suggestion on how to get frames in a loop. Tried using Clock.schedule_interval() but may be my method is not correct.